# if / else statements not working within AJAX response function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm completely bewildered here. Before I start I should say that all my code is working 100%, and this issue has appeared for no apparent reason.

An AJAX call is made when a user clicks a button, and a form is returned if the conditions are met. Then when a user submits the form, it makes another AJAX call and submits the data, again, if the conditions are met. The data submits successfully, and returns either 'success', or 'error_1', 'error_2' etc.

What's not working is simply the if/else statements within response function in the JS.

Here is the PHP callback function:

```
function submit_entry() {

// my variables

if($current_words > $max_words) {

    echo 'max_words';

} elseif($current_words < $min_words) {

    echo 'min_words';

} else {

    $post_data = array(
        'ID' => $entryID,
        'post_date' => date('YmdHis'),
        'post_content' => $text,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    wp_update_post($post_data);

    echo 'success';

}

exit;

}
```

Here is the AJAX call:

```
jQuery('#entrySubmit').click(function() {
    jQuery.post(
        MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        {
            action : 'submit-entry',
            etc.
        },
        function( response ) {

            if(response == 'max_words') {

                jQuery('#add_entry_error').html('You exceeded the maximum number of words.');

            } else if(response == 'min_words') {

                jQuery('#add_entry_error').html('You have not written enough words, please write more.');               

            } else if(response == 'success') {

                jQuery('#add_entry_step_1').slideUp();
                jQuery('#add_entry_step_2').slideDown();
                jQuery('#add_entry_error').html('');

            } 
            jQuery('#add_entry_error').append(response);
        }
    );  
});
```

Here the `jQuery('#add_entry_error').append(response);` line successfully appends either `min_words`, `max_words`, or `success` - so why aren't the if statements working???
There is no error in the console, and as I said it all works apart from the response.

Comment: Have you checked if the ifs are entered at all? Have you tried debugging, or at least put an alert in there? Have you checked if there isn't any whitespace before or after response?

Comment: try to alert your response and see what you are getting

Comment: I'm getting the expected response when using `alert`, it's as if the if statements are just refusing to work.

Comment: Are you *actually* getting the expected response, or something like `[whitespace]expected response[linebreak][whitespace]`? Check with something like Fiddler2 or Wireshark, and see what are the actual responses that go over the network.

Comment: Well I thought whitespace could be the issue, but there is definitely none in the callback, but I'll do what you suggest.

Comment: Ok it's working again except I have no idea why... I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are two logical possibilites: Either the `if` statements aren't working, or the code inside them doesn't work. Try putting an `alert` or something inside the braces and see what happens!

Comment: I'm getting the expected response when using `alert`, it's as if the if statements are just refusing to work.

Comment: no I mean put the alert into the part behind "if". If you're getting the expected response there as well, it can't be the if statements

Answer (score 1):

I found something really weird during Firebug debugging.

It was some comments in my PHP file that were being appended to the response text.

Make sure if you are using a middle PHP file to process the requests that there are no comments like these `<!--` in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use

```
response.responseText
```

instead of

```
response
```

in conditions ??

-Vinay